# Which patent claims did George Selden believe Henry Ford violated?

Tags: patent-infringement, claims, inventor-declaration, us549160

I'm trying to find information for a report analyzing the Ford Vs. Selden case at the turn of the 20th century. I can find a lot of brief case summaries, but I cannot find anything that specifies what exact claims Selden believed Ford violated in his patent.

Here is the patent for your information: [US549160](http://www.google.com/patents/US549160)

Comment: I'm not sure if a discussion about a specific case would be on-topic here?

Answer (score 1):

Funnily enough, a few months ago I stumbled upon a very detailed account of Selden, his work, his patents and legal battles against his competitors:

http://www.kcstudio.com/selden.html

Selden is another historical figure that some contemporary articles like to paint as a historical example of a "patent troll", but this account suggests otherwise. He does seem to be one of the earlier practitioner of "submarine" patents, although, if this account is accurate, he was so far ahead of his time that in his case it seems justified.

It's a fascinating read and has lots of old photos and newspaper clippings to go with the narrative. Although I haven't taken the time to verify its accuracy, it generally seems to gel with most of the document and photographic evidence included.